# Preventing java.lang.StackOverflow error simple sql pool

Tags: java

so I am running multiple sql calls and I have a custom 'sql pool' of connections, however it's starting to send java.lang.stackoverflow errors. How would I go about preventing this. Here's my current code.

```
public static synchronized PooledSqlConnection getConnectionFromPool() {
    for(PooledSqlConnection connection : pooledSqlConnections) {
        if(connection.getConnection() == null) {
            connection.setUpConnection();
        }
        if(!connection.isInUse()) {
            connection.setInUse(true);
            return connection;
        }
    }
    return getConnectionFromPool();
}
```

Would something like this work well?

```
public static synchronized PooledSqlConnection getConnectionFromPool() {
    boolean foundPool = false;
    while(!foundPool) {
        for(PooledSqlConnection connection : pooledSqlConnections) {
            if(connection.getConnection() == null) {
                connection.setUpConnection();
            }
            if(!connection.isInUse()) {
                connection.setInUse(true);
                foundPool = true;
                return connection;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Every time a connection is used, it's marked as in-use, once it's finished it marks it as not in use.

Comment: Why is your return statement calling itself? Once the loop is finished it is going to continue to call the function indefinitely, causing a stack overflow.

Comment: The return kills it! `return getConnectionFromPool();` What is the utility of this recursion?

Comment: You should either return `null` at the end or throw a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: The idea of putting a loop is better, but your `foundPool` variable isn't useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your decision to make a recursive call when you fail to find an available connection doesn't seem like a good idea. When you run out of available connections, it causes infinite recursion and `StackOverflowError`.

Instead of the recursive call, you can wrap your `for` loop with another `for` loop that would sleep after each iteration of the inner loop (to give the occupied connections time to be released).

Or, as an alternative, throw an exception if there are no available connections. This will make it the responsibility of the caller of `getConnectionFromPool()` to retry when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would something like this work well (edited my post)

Comment: @PhillipJ returning null when you fail to find an available connection will solve the `StackOverflowError` issue, but I believe an exception would be cleaner (since failure to obtain a connection is a failure, that should be handled by exception handling, not by checking if the method returned `null`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty likely that the stack overflow is caused by the recursive call to `getConnectionFromPool()`. To avoid it, you want to derecursify your method, as follows:

```
public static synchronized PooledSqlConnection getConnectionFromPool() {
    while (true) {
        for(PooledSqlConnection connection : pooledSqlConnections) {
            if(connection.getConnection() == null) {
                connection.setUpConnection();
            }
            if(!connection.isInUse()) {
                connection.setInUse(true);
                return connection;
            }
        }
        // If we reach this stage, there is no available connection.
        // FIXME: Add some form of sleep and/or wait
        // to be notified once a connection is available.
    }
}
```

**Note** I don't know enough about `PooledSqlConnection` to be sure that this snippet fully works.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Is there any reason to put Thread.sleep(X) instead of just making it continue to loop?

Comment: Well, if you don't sleep, you're going to go through this loop millions of times per second, eating CPU and battery like crazy.